# How can I do a header for a CSV using StringBuilder? C#

Tags: c#, csv

I will edit my post because I couldn't express very well.
I want to do this:

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5906o.png)

And I don't know how to do a unique header. I achieved this:

[Achieved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZIUn.png)

but now I need to do the header. I will post more of my code here:

```
    protected override void OnBarUpdate()
    {
        
        if (BarsInProgress != 0) 
             return;

        if (CurrentBars[0] < Shift)
            return;         
        
        
        string header = "Time" + ";" + "Close[0]" + ";" + "ATR_7" + ";" + "VOL_7" + ";" + "LABEL";
        string Label = "NULL";
        
        if(Alcista)
        {
            if(Open[0] >= Open[Shift - 1] && Open[0]/Open[Shift - 1] >= 1.0001)
            {
                Label = "UP";                   
            }
            else
            {
                Label = "DOWN";
            }
        }
        switch(Indicar2_Sesgo)
        {
            
            
            case Sesgo.Alcista:
                StringBuilder csvcontent = new StringBuilder();
                

                csvcontent.AppendLine(Convert.ToString(Times[0][0].TimeOfDay + ";" + Close[0] + ";" + ATR1[0] + ";" + VOL1[0] + ";" + Label));
                
                string csvpath = "D:\\xyz.csv";
                File.AppendAllText(csvpath, csvcontent.ToString());
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't appear that you're trying to build a CSV file. There are semi-colons rather than commas.

Comment: It might be good to use a csv library

Comment: There is no need to call `Convert.ToString` on a string. It's already a string.

Comment: the header line is just a literal "Time,Close, Atr1,Atr2" for example

Comment: It's unlikely that you need `File.AppendAllText` when writing a header as the header is usually the first line. `File.WriteAllText` is probably the better choice.

Comment: Thanks for your response but I have a config with ";" instead of ",".

Comment: I deleted my comment re `StringBuilder`. You do need it here as you're creating more than one line.

Comment: @Enigmativity When I use WriteAllText it only write one line, it's fine for the header but not for the rest of the csv. I have to create like 500k lines. With AppendAllText it is very simple because it print all the data.
I'm new at this, I know that it could be a better code

Answer (score 1):

It is a little difficult to know what your output is supposed to look like, but if you are simply trying to write a header, your code may look something like this:

```
var csvPath = "D:\\xyz.csv";
var csvHeader = "Time;Close;Atr1;Atr2";
File.WriteAllText(csvPath, csvHeader + Environment.NewLine);
```

As others have mentioned you would be better off using a helper library (like csvhelper) and setting the delimiter to a semicolon.

Comment: the question is about the header row, not the data row(s)

Comment: thanks, the question is quite confusing. Updated my answer based on your comment

Comment: Thanks for your response, I edited the post to offer more information about what I need.